# C# property inheritance from parent class

Tags: c#, list, inheritance, parent

I want my Player objects to inherit the sum of chips in the Tournament. I get (Attempted to divide by zero.) and I think that's because it fails to inherit Chips from the parent Tournament object. Why is this not working?

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Tournament = new Tournament();
        Tournament.PlayerList.Add(new Player("Hero", 5000));
        Tournament.PlayerList.Add(new Player("Villain1", 3000));
        Tournament.PlayerList.Add(new Player("Villain2", 4000));

        MessageBox.Show(Tournament.PlayerList[0].StackPercentage.ToString());
    }
}

public class Tournament
{
    public List<Player> PlayerList { get; set; }
    public int Chips
    {
        get
        {
            return PlayerList.Sum(S => S.Stack);
        }
    }

    public Tournament()
    {
        PlayerList = new List<Player>();
    }
}

public class Player : Tournament
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public int Stack { get; set; }
    public double StackPercentage
    {
        get
        {
            return Stack / Chips;
        }
    }

    public Player(string _ID, int _Stack)
    {
        ID = _ID;
        Stack = _Stack;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `Player` does not inherit `Chips` from `Tournament`? I believe it does.

Comment: I don't believe this code can compile -- you have a variable with the same name as a type here `public Tournament Tournament { get; set; }`

Comment: Just because something is inherited does not make it global / static.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not derive Player from Tournament.  By doing so, you're saying each Player IS a Tournament.

Try something like this:

```
public interface IPlayer {}

public abstract class Player : IPlayer 
{
  public ITournament CurrentTournament { get; set; }
}

public class PokerPlayer : Player 
{
  public PokerPlayer() {}
  public int CurrentChips { get; set; }

  public double StackPercentage 
  {
    get { return this.CurrentChips / (PokerTournament)this.CurrentTournament.StartingChips; }
  }
}

public interface ITournament {}

public abstract class Tournament : ITournament
{
  public List<Player> Players { get; set; }
  public int PlayerCount { get { return this.Players.Count; } }
}

public class PokerTournament : Tournament 
{
  private PokerTournament() {}
  public PokerTournament(int startingChips)
  { 
    if(startingChips < 1) throw new ArgumentException("Invalid starting amount.", "startingChips");
    this.StartingChips = startingChips; 
  }

  public int StartingChips { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Inheritance seems fine.

I think you'r problem is that `PlayerList` is probably empty or the chips of every `Player` in the `List` are equal to *zero* and therefore the sum is *zero* too.

Make `StackPercentage` take into account the possibility of `Chips` being equal to *zero* if it makes sense or fix the logic that populates `PlayerList` so that `Chips` can not be *zero* ever.

**EDIT**: You have editted your question but the code you have written wouldn't even compile...I'm not sure what your issue is unless you clarify your code.

Try this:

```
public Form1()
{
    ....
    Tournament tournament = new Tournament();
    tournament.PlayerList.Add(new Player("Hero", 5000));
    tournament.PlayerList.Add(new Player("Villain1", 3000));
    tournament.PlayerList.Add(new Player("Villain2", 4000));
    int chips = tournament.PlayerList[0].StackPercentage.ToString();
}
```

Anyway this wont work. See [Haris Hasan's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/421611/haris-hasan) answer for details. Basically `tournament` is not the same object as `(Tournament)PlayerList[0]`. Keep in mind that everytime you create a `Player` instance a new `Tournament` base class instance is created whith its correponding emtpy `PlayerList`.

You should not be using inheritance here at all. A `Player` and a `Tournament` have no inheritance relationship at all. A `Player` is not a `Tournament`. Get rid of the inheritance relationship and simply move `StackPercentage` to the `Tournament` class and convert it into a method that takes a `Player` instance as an argument:

```
  public double StackPercentage(Player player)
  {
       return player.Stack/this.Chips;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem in this code is you are assuming `Tournament.PlayerList[0]` will point to the same player list as instance `Tournament` is doing but this won't be the case. The `PlayerList[0]`'s  PlayerList collection is empty.

```
 public double StackPercentage
    {
        get
        {
            //Chips here is 0 because the PlayerList of Player instance is empty
            return Stack / Chips;
        }
    }
```

The Player class has it's own `PlayerList`.

Comment: So every time I instantiate a new Player it will also trigger the constructor of Tournament and create a new empty playerlist. How do I make a property (in the Player class) that is dependent of the stack size of the other players then?

Comment: Basically `Player` is inheriting from `Tournament` so whenever a new instance of `Player` will be created, first constructor of `Tournament` will be called and then constructor of `Player`. Constructor of `Tournament` will initialize `PlayerList` for `Player` instance

Comment: If you want to share information between instances/classes you can either pass this information through parameters or you can declare some global values which are accessible to all classes/instances

Comment: Good job finding the "0 count" issue, but that's not the real problem.  The inheritance is really what is wrong here which is causing the zero count issue.