# Polymorphism: getting it right

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, polymorphism

I'm trying to get my head around a polymorphism/inheritance situation in C#.

What I have right now is these classes:

```
Lease (the base class containing the general data)
PrivateLease (inheriting from the Lease class)
BusinessLease (inheriting from the Lease class)
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
Lease lease = new PrivateLease();
```

This works at the moment, but I am not able to access the properties on the `PrivateLease` object when doing this. At least not without casting the `Lease` object to a `PrivateLease` object first.

I'd like the `Lease` object to be the general object of either a `PrivateLease` or `BusinessLease` object which holds all the data for one of the objects. Then when inserting/updating/deleting to the database I'm going to ask which type it is first to dertermine which tables to insert the data into.

I've got a strange feeling that the above is not the right approach to solve this problem. Does anyone have any hints on this? :-) I've searched on google and read in my programming books and everyone suggests this approach of having a base class and then inherit from it to the other classes.

Any help/hint is greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Should've elaborated a bit on this from the beginning, I'm sorry for that!

The above mentioned classes are merely just holding data from the UI of my ASP.NET solution to  perform CRUD operations against the database via a Data Access Layer. So bascially these classes only contains a bunch of properties to hold data. I.e:

```
public class Lease
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
    public string TypeOfRental { get; set; }
    public string RentalPeriod { get; set; }
    public DateTime TakeoverDate { get; set; }        
}

public class PrivateLease : Lease
{
    public string Floor { get; set; }
    public string Side { get; set; }
    public int FloorSize { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfRooms { get; set; }
}
```

etc..

The `PrivateLease` and `BusinessLease` classes are different because of the different leaseing-variables that exists in the real world :-)

Basically I could just go with the two separate `PrivateLease` and `BusinessLease` objects, but since the model dictates that an `Address` object can hold one or more `Lease`s, this is not an option.

To me it seems like I'm going to go through a major casting hell both on the ASP.NET frontend and on the DAL? :-/

Comment: See my solution here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8636568/c-sharp-property-inheritance-from-parent-class/8637104#8637104

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't decide (choose a logic) on the layer of consumer, but let to decide by the classes themselves:

```
// or you ILease interface if a parent class will not contain any shared logic
abstract class Lease
{
    public abstract void Do();

    // example of shared logic
    protected void Save(Lease l) { }
}

class PrivateLease : Lease
{
    public override void Do() { // private logic here }
}

class BusinessLease : Lease
{
    public override void Do() { // business logic here }
}
```

Usage:

```
Lease l = ...
l.Do(); // execute the logic
```

---

You may want to create a factory for objects creation:

```
static class LeaseFactory<T> where T : Lease, new() // constraint to require default constructor existence
{
    public static Leas Create()
    {
        return new T();
    }
}
```

Comment: a bit unfortunate naming the method 'Lease' :)

Comment: @NSGaga: Agree. Renamed to just `Do()`.

Comment: Hi abatishchev, thanks a lot for your help :-) Thing is that my classes aren't really containing any logic per say, they just contain a bunch of properties to hold data (I guess you could look at them as a DTO, really), so there will be no methods to actually override in this situation :-)

Comment: @bomortensen: "Properties only containers" are usually called POCOs, you could meet such a abbreviation already. Usually in MVC, there are 2 approaches to spread the logic: thin model and thick model. First contains data only (pure POCOs), and second - logic also. I think your case is good for 2nd way. Something like `LeaseRepository.Do()` will accept `Lease` and call `Do()`.

Comment: Hi again abatischev. I haven't really dug into what POCO is yet, but to me it seems that the first (thin model) seems to fit my needs best since there aren't any logic in my classes at all. They only contain properties to hold/transfer data to/from the UI and the DAL.

Comment: Having searched further it seems that I can't do what I want by polymorphism and/or inheritance. I can do this: PrivateLease pvtLease = new PrivateLease(); and then have access to all of the base class' properties including the properties on the PrivateLease class. Although this means a lot of casting here and there, it seems to be the way to go, sadly :-/

Comment: @bomortensen: Please elaborate your last sentence. Where you afraid you will have to cast?

Comment: Sure, abatischev :-) Having a Lease object on, say the DAL, where I need to create a PrivateLease in the database, I will first have to cast the Lease object to a PrivateLease object before I am able to finally make use of all properties on both the PrivateLease object and the base, Lease class. Don't know if that makes any sense? :-)

Comment: @bomortensen: Why don't put `Save()` logic into child classes? So appropriate method will know what fields to save in db.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, abatischev. By logic, do you mean the database logic to save the child classes data, or? Excuse me if i'm a bit slow on this ;-) thanks again!

Comment: @bomortensen: Right. Dedicate saving to database to child classes. So DAL just calls Save() on a Lease object. But actually that a child class with its own set of properties and rules for saving. The same for creation: you have a generic factory class which sends down to child classes, which knowns exactly how to create itself, etc.

Comment: Abatischev, that makes sense :-) only thing i'm thinking of is that i should still have dedicated methods on the DAL for creating a PrivateLease and a BusinessLease in the database. These methods will then accept the corresponding lease childclass. Also, these methods would then be called from the childclasses. Am I totally off on this approach? ;-)

Comment: @bomortensen: Indeed why not? You anyway will have a high-level method for creation, "point of exit". Probably you can hide 2 different methods/classes (or more) existence with generic: `public static Lease Create<T>() where T : Lease { return new T(); }`. So concrete child class constructor will be called, where all the actual logic is placed. Usage: (see my answer updated).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9809/discussion-between-bomortensen-and-abatishchev)

Answer (score 3):

You're right in the basic approach of having a base class.

What you need to do is to put any *common* properties in the base class. Then if you have different business rules, those can be implemented with virtual functions, being called polymorphically.

```
abstract class Lease
{
  public int MonthlyCost {get;set;}

  public string CustomerName {get;set;}

  // Declare that all Leases have to have an IncreaseCost method.
  public abstract void IncreaseCost();
}

class PrivateLease : Lease
{
  // Private leases are incremented by an absolute number (10).
  public override void IncreaseCost()
  {
    MonthlyCost += 10;
  }
}

class BusinessLease : Lease
{
  // Business leases are incremented by 10%.
  public override void IncreaseCost()
  {
    MonthlyCost *= 1.10;
  }
}

// Somewhere in your code...
Lease lease = new PrivateLease();

// This call is polymorphic. It will use the actual type of the lease object.
lease.IncreaseCost();
```

Comment: Hi Anders, thanks a lot for your input :-) So basically I have to declare my properties on the PrivateLease and BusinessLease as public virtual string MyProperty { get; set; } ?

Comment: If it's just a simple property you shouldn't make it `virtual`. It is quite rarely that there is any benefit in making properties `virtual`. Methods on the other hand are often worth making `virtual`.

Comment: @AndersAbel - `PrivateLease` and `BusinessLease` should probably inherit from `Lease` before overriding `IncreaseCost` ;)

Comment: @MetroSmurf: Of course, I've edited my answer. Interesting that nobody else has seen it in two months... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In the modern OOD you can use `interfaces`, for this situation.

**Edit:**

In my opinion, to avoid casting, you can have multiple interfaces for multiple purposes. then `PrivateLease` and `BusinessLease` can implement the appropriate ones.

```
interface IWrite
{
    string Data { get; set; }
    void Write();
}

interface IRead
{
    string Data { get; set; }
    void Read();
}

public class Lease
{
    //..
}

public class PrivateLease : Lease, IWrite, IRead
{
    // other implementations
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public void Read()
    {
        //..
    }
    public void Write()
    {
        //..
    }
}
public class BusinessLease : Lease, IRead
{
    // other implementations
    public string Data { get; set; }
    public void Read()
    {
        //..
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mouliyan, thanks for your help :-) Still, if I do this: ILease lease = new PrivateLease(); I won't be able to access properties on the PrivateLease object if they aren't implemented via the ILease interface, which I'm not interested in since the Lease class should hold all the general data for the Lease type objects..

Comment: you can implement different interfaces for related properties.

Answer (score 0):

In Lease class add virtual method called DBUpdate and **override** it in both the derived classes.

Let's say some Utility class has LeaseDBOperation Method looks like this :

```
public static void LeaseDBOperation (Lease anylease)
{

  anyleaase.DBUpdate();
}
```

you can call this method as :

```
var pl = new PrivateLease();
..set all the properties of **pl**
//call this for db operations  :
Utility.LeaseDBOperation(pl)
```

Here in LeaseDBOperation method , if based on the type send , DBUpdate method of required class will be called.

Comment: Hi Dhananjay, thanks for your input :-) That's more or less how I am doing it now. Having a CreateLease(Lease lease) on my DAL where I'm creating the lease in the database. My main "issue" on this is that I will have to check of the lease object is either a PrivateLease or a BusinessLease before inserting anything into the database..

Comment: actually not. anyleaase.DBUpdate() method will take care or it. DBUpdate() method is written into both the lease classes (private and business lease.).  you dont have to worry about which one you are updating..

Answer (score -1):

```
Lease l = (Lease)sth;

if (l is PrivateLease)
{
    PrivateLease p = (PrivateLease)l;    
    //do private logic here
}
else if (l if BussinessLease)
{    
    BussinessLease b = (BunessinessLease)l;
    //do bussiness logic here
}
```

Comment: A conditional like this is actually a step backwards for polymorphism.  Take a look here: http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html and here: http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism, among others.

Comment: @David: Agree. Use polymorphism to allow classes themselves to decide what logic to execute.

Comment: That would be a violation of the open/closed principle for those who are fans of SOLID.